# Is it OK to store Mongo _id as a string, instead of ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, bson

This question has been asked a few times, but none of the 'pros' for using ObjectId seem to apply to my case, and the questions are all quite old. I'm wondering if there's anything I'm missing.

Specifically, I'm deciding between these two options:

1. Store `_id` as an `ObjectId` in the DB.
2. Store `_id` as the string representation of an ObjectId in the DB.

My understanding of the reasons to favour storing an `ObjectId` object over its string representation:

- They're 12 bytes instead of 24. This is only 12 MB per million records, a tiny fraction of the document size, and a few cents of extra infrastructure, so doesn't warrant adding complexity to my application code.
- They're 'faster'. I keep hearing this, but no one says *how much* faster, which makes me wonder if there's no difference and everyone just repeats what they heard from someone else. I found [these benchmarks](https://github.com/Restuta/mongo.Guid-vs-ObjectId-performance#mongoguid-vs-objectid-performance), where read times for single items are identical. There's differences when writing a million records, but I won't be doing that. Also benchmarks like this aren't taking into account the extra time taken to convert an object (coming over the network) from string IDs to `ObjectId` objects for every write operation. I suspect having to add a loop on the app server to parse incoming data and convert strings to `new ObjectId(item._id)` for the million records would level the results.
- Using `ObjectId` is the 'normal' way to do it. I'm somewhat swayed by this argument, I don't like doing things the weird way. But as it results in extra code that's prone to bugs, it's not a good enough reason on its own.

The reason for wanting to do option 2 is that I'm converting to/from string/ObjectId in many places in my app as data flows between userland and the DB. Not just for `_id` fields, but for `otherItemId` and `listOfRelatedThingIds`. They all get implicitly converted to strings on the way out (over the network) and need to manually be converted back on the way in. It's not the worst thing in the world, but if there's *no good reason* to be doing it, then I'll switch to strings in the DB.

Comment: I think the question is pointless. But you could discuss whether it makes sense to use the MongoDB internal `ObjectId` or an self-developed customize string/number for the `_id` field.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that you think my question is pointless. Now if someone asks, what does Wernfried Domscheit think about this, I will say, without hesitation, "oh Wernfried thinks the question is pointless"

Comment: Well, the question itself is not pointless. But the approach to use a string for the ObjectId does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

The ObjectID type has a built-in timestamp for sorting. Four bytes of the 12 bytes you reference are dedicated to representing the time since the unix epoch in seconds. When you create ObjectIDs they are sortable with each other automatically based on the order in which they were created.

You can use the .getTimeStamp() function on your ObjectID to return the timestamp.

```
var id = new ObjectId();
console.log(id.getTimestamp())
```

You may think you're saving some infrastructure costs on the storage of your documents, but there is also savings in the overhead when it comes to accessing, sorting, and indexing as well.

Comment: The string representation of ObjectId is also sortable, so this isn't a reason to store the data as an `ObjectId` (also I have no requirement to sort by "date the ID was generated"). You say "...savings in the overhead when it comes to accessing, sorting, and indexing as well". What size are the savings? Can you link to something that demonstrates these savings?